# Angular 5 show "No data found" on ngIf empty results

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm using Angular 5 and I'm building a list of items with some buttons that filter the list. What I'm struggling to do is show a "No data found" kind of message when one of those filters hide every item of the list.

It's basically this:

**The filter buttons**

```
<div padding>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="filter" (ionChange)="onFilterChange()">
        <ion-segment-button value="all">
            All
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="2">
            Pending
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="1">
            Confirmed
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</div>
```

**The list**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let r of (reservations | async)">
    <ion-card *ngIf="(filter == 'all' || filter == r.confirmed)">
        <ion-item>
            Item
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>    
</ion-list>
```

*Note: I'm using the async pipe because data comes from Firebase Realtime Database.*

So, all my items are in a state of pending (having confirmed: 2), so when I click on the Confirmed button, all the items on the list get hidden, which is perfect. But how can I show a "No data found" message instead of an empty list?

I've tried the else condition, but I'm getting multiple "No data found" messages (one for each hidden item):

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let r of (reservations | async)">
    <ion-card *ngIf="(filter == 'all' || filter == r.confirmed); else empty;">
        <ion-item>
            Item
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>    
</ion-list>
<ng-template #empty>
    No data found...
</ng-template>
```

So what's the correct way of achieving this?
Thanks.

Comment: ```<ion-card *ngIf="filter != 'all' && filter != r.confirmed">
    <ion-item>
        No Data
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>```

Comment: Try moving <ng-template #empty> inside of the ion-list

Comment: @mast3rd3mon That way it gives me duplicated "No Data", one for each hidden list item...

Comment: @BorisLobanov Yes, I've tried that but the result is the same...

Comment: This is not a good use case for `else`. Just use `<div *ngIf ="(reservations | async).filter(f)">None</div>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad not a really good solution from the performance point of view

Comment: @Jota.Toledo it is simple. Once correct results are obtained, it can be optimized if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you shouldnt display the raw list of reservations. Instead, display the already filtered list:

component.html

```
<ion-segment [formControl]="status" (ionChange)="onFilterChange()">
    <ion-segment-button value="2">
        Pending
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="1">
        Confirmed
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion>

<div *ngIf="empty$ | async; else notEmpty">
   Nothing
</div>
<ng-template #notEmpty>
   <ion-list *ngFor="let reservation of reservations$ | async">
        <ion-card>
            <ion-item>
                Item
            </ion-item>
        </ion-card>    
    </ion-list>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

status= new FormControl;
reservations$: Observable<IReservation[]>;
empty$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(){
   this.reservations$ = combineLatest(rawReservations$,this.status.valueChanges,this._applyFilter);
  this.empty$ = this.reservations$.map(reservations => reservations.length === 0);
}

private _applyFilter(reservations: IReservation[], status: number): IReservation[]{
  let result = reservations;
  //apply filter logic
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a smart approach. I'll try to convert your code (I'm using Angularfire2 and Firebase) and see if it works.

Comment: This can indeed by further improved by using some more advanced techniques (presentation component + transclusion); you could drop the empty$ and the ng-if-else. If you are interested in it let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: Avoid multiple subscriptions by doing this: `*ngIf="(reservations$ | async) as reservations; else notEmpty"` then `*ngFor="let reservation of reservations"` (no second async pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach and tell me if it works for you.

**Component:**

```
// control variable
  dataAvailable = false;

  onFilterChange(filterType: number) {
    // your code and logic

    // This is pretty ugly, make it prettier please...    

    // checking if exists at least 1 reservation with confirmed = 1 | 2 (depends on argument).
    this.dataAvailable = this.reservations.filter(res => res.confirmed === filterType).length > 0;
  }
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="dataAvailable; then printData else empty"></div>

<ng-template #printData>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let r of (reservations | async)">
      <ion-card>
          <ion-item>
              Item
          </ion-item>
      </ion-card>    
  </ion-list>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #empty>
    No data found...
</ng-template>
```

So, my idea is that first we check if *it's worth* to loop through the data in the template. We check this in the component, we see if it exists any reservation with the filtered values.

If it doesn't exist, we won't loop, we just display (no data).
If it does exist though, we'll loop and print them...

Does it makes sense? Hope it helps you or at least points you to the right direction!

Comment: thanks I guess this would work, but decided to go with @Jota.Toledo because a very large list could perform better with his code