# Angular + Ionic 4, show "nothing here" if observable is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

HTML:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group>
      <ion-item class="ion-no-padding" *ngFor="let service of services | async">
        <ion-label>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size="12">
                {{ service.name }}
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="end" value="{{ service.id }}"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
```

and my page.ts

```
services: Observable<Service[]>;
// db service conneting to firebase
  ngOnInit() {
    this.services = this.db.getServicesFromVenue(this.routeParams.venueID);
  }
```

service:

```
  getServicesFromVenue(venueID: string): Observable<Service[]> {
    this.serviceCollection = this.afs.collection<Service>('services', ref => ref.where('venue', '==', venueID));
    return this.services = this.serviceCollection
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        })
      );
  }
```

everything working very well, but i dont know how to show message "no services" where i dont get any results. Trying various methods, but nothing works for me:

```
  <ion-list *ngIf="services | async as service; else noServicesBlock">
```

give me nothing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you define an empty output? null? undefined?

Comment: Null. I mean there's no data to show :)

Comment: ngif will eveluate only if there is emission, so if you collection doesn't emit value it'll just hang there, or you can give it an initial output of false, and return a false result if data is empty

Comment: Could you show me example of code? Sorry, im totally newbie at angular and rxjs.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768078/angular-5-show-no-data-found-on-ngif-empty-results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with a `null` value , using `startWith(false)` so it'll show noServicesBlock. Also add condition check to see if actions are empty (empty array will evaluate to true []) and return a false value.

```
getServicesFromVenue(venueID: string): Observable<any> {
    this.serviceCollection = this.afs.collection<Service>('services', ref => ref.where('venue', '==', venueID));
    return this.services = this.serviceCollection
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => {
          if(!actions.length) return false;
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        }),
        startWith(false)
      );
  }
```

Comment: There's problem: Type 'Observable<boolean | { id: any; name: string; venue: string; basePrice: number; timeDuration: number; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Service[]>'.
  Type 'boolean | { id: any; name: string; venue: string; basePrice: number; timeDuration: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Service[]'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Service[]'.

Comment: change return type to Observable<Service[] | boolean> or Observable<any>

Comment: also this.afs.collection<any>